# PHP - Strip a specific string out of a string

Tags: php, string, strip

I've got this string, but I need to remove specific things out of it...

Original String: `hr-165-34.sh-290-92.ch-215-84.hd-180-1.lg-280-64`.

The string I need: `sh-290-92.ch-215-84.lg-280-64`.

I need to remove `hr-165-34. and hd-180-1`.
!

EDIT: Ahh ive hit a snag!

the string always changes, so the bits i need to remove like "hr-165-34." always change, it will always be "hr-SOMETHING-SOMETHING."

So the methods im using wont work!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Depends on why you want to remove exactly those Substrigs...

- If you always want to remove exactly those substrings, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
- If you always want to remove the characters at the same position, you can use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
- If you always want to remove substrings between two dots, that match certain criteria, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Could you provide an example of str_replace, im a bit stuck using it

Comment: As you can see in other answers, you just replace the substring you want to remove with an empty string. The first parameter of str_replace is an array of strings, which you want to replace, the second parameter is the string which you want to use as replacement. Actually both parameters can be strings or arrays...

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'hr-165-34.sh-290-92.ch-215-84.hd-180-1.lg-280-64';
$new_str = str_replace(array('hr-165-34.', 'hd-180-1.'), '', $str);
```

Info on [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way of doing this is to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$ostr = "hr-165-34.sh-290-92.ch-215-84.hd-180-1.lg-280-64";
$nstr = str_replace("hr-165-34.","",$ostr);
$nstr = str_replace("hd-180-1.","",$nstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$string = 'hr-165-34.sh-290-92.ch-215-84.hd-180-1.lg-280-64';

// define all strings to delete is easier by using an array
$delete_substrings = array('hr-165-34.', 'hd-180-1.');
$string = str_replace($delete_substrings, '', $string);


assert('$string == "sh-290-92.ch-215-84.lg-280-64" /* Expected result: string = "sh-290-92.ch-215-84.lg-280-64" */');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out!

```
$figure = $q['figure']; // hr-165-34.sh-290-92.ch-215-84.hd-180-1.lg-280-64

$s = $figure;
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('/hr(.*?)\./s', $s, $matches);

$s = $figure;
$matches2 = array();
$t = preg_match('/hd(.*?)\./s', $s, $matches2);

$s = $figure;
$matches3 = array();
$t = preg_match('/ea(.*?)\./s', $s, $matches3);

$str = $figure;
$new_str = str_replace(array($matches[0], $matches2[0], $matches3[0]), '', $str);
echo($new_str);
```

Thanks guys!