# C# Splitting a specific string for specific data

Tags: c#, string, split

I have this string...

```
lg-270-110.sh-300-110.hd-180-1.hr-155-61.ea-1403-62.cc-3007-110-110.ch-220-63.ca-3084-64-64
```

The string is always changing...

How would i get the data between two certain points...

What i need really is to extract the hd-180-1. and the hr-155-61. and remove them from the string

But you see the data isnt always hd-180-1. - It could be hd-171-4. - So i need to delete the data between HD and . programatically

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Strip a specific string out of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382611/php-strip-a-specific-string-out-of-a-string)

Comment: One approach that is very flexible but might not be performant enough is to use my [sscanf() Replacement for .NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net). It allows you to define placeholders and extract whatever parts you need.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work.

string s = "lg-270-110.sh-300-110.hd-180-1.hr-155-61.ea-1403-62.cc-3007-110-110.ch-220-63.ca-3084-64-64";
int start = s.IndexOf("hd");
int end = s.IndexOf(".")
string result = s.Substring(start, end - start -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a job for Regular Expressions

```
string s = "lg-270-110.sh-300-110.hd-180-1.hr-155-61.ea-1403-62.cc-3007-110-110.ch-220-63.ca-3084-64-64";

s = Regex.Replace(s, @"hd.*?\.", "");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"hr.*?\.", "");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

[here's my favorite regex reference](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

you can also use regex to match your pattern

```
string s = "lg-270-110.sh-300-110.hd-180-1.hr-155-61.ea-1403-62.cc-3007-110-110.ch-220-63.ca-3084-64-64";

Regex r = new Regex(@"hd.*?\.");
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(s).Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a combination of [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) and [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (or possibly regular expressions). You will really need to understand and explain *exactly* how your string is structured in order to extract the data you want.

**IndexOf** searches strings. It returns the first occurrence of a letter in a string. It can also find a substring in the string. It is often used in looping constructs. It returns negative one when nothing is found.

**Substring** extracts strings. It requires that you indicate a start index and a length. It then returns a completely new string with the characters in that range

```
        string data = "lg-270-110.sh-300-110.hd-180-1.hr-155-61.ea-1403-62.cc-3007-110-110.ch-220-63.ca-3084-64-64";

        int indexOf_hd = data.IndexOf("hd");
        int indexOf_fullstop = data.IndexOf(".", indexOf_hd);

        string extracteddata = data.Substring(indexOf_hd, indexOf_fullstop - indexOf_hd);

        // extracteddata = hd-180-1
```

Also look at [examples with IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof) and [examples with substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could also use string.split:

```
List<string> list = yourString.Split(".");
List<string> keeping = list.Where(s => !s.Contains("hd") && !s.Contains("hr"))
return String.Join(".", keeping);
```

Comment: It can sometimes be the third item, it is random you see.

Comment: you could split and then match each entry to keep or remove, if that makes thing easier.

Comment: @x06265616e, I edited the answer to reflect the random location.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression

```
string data = "lg-270-110.sh-300-110.hd-180-1.hr-155-61.ea-1403-62.cc-3007-110-110.ch-220-63.ca-3084-64-64";

//Match things that are preceded by a dot (.) (or the beginning of input)
// that begin with 'h' followed by a single letter, then dash, three digits, 
// a dash, at least one digit, followed by a period (or the end of input)
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=(^|\.))h\w-\d{3}-\d+(\.|$)");

//Get the matching strings found
var matches = rx.Matches(data);

//Print out the matches, trimming off the dot at the end
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value.TrimEnd('.'));
}

//Get a new copy of the string with the matched sections removed
var result = rx.Replace(data, "").TrimEnd('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a function online that works...

```
            public static string RemoveBetween(string s, string begin, string end)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}{1}", begin, end));
                return regex.Replace(s, string.Empty);
            }
```

Comment: What are `begin` and `end` you pass to that function?